# How to select constructor based on cv qualifiers in C++?

Tags: c++

How could I invoke a different constructor based on cv qualifiers of a created object? Example:

```
#include <low_level_lib.h>

struct my_buffer
{
private:
    low_level_lib::buffer_id id;
public:    
    my_buffer(const data* const data_to_store_)
    {
        id = low_level_lib::create_buffer();
        low_level_lib::store_buffer_data(id, usage::dynamic);
    }

    my_buffer(const data* const data_to_store_) const //compilation fails here
    {
        id = low_level_lib::create_buffer();
        low_level_lib::store_buffer_data(id, usage::static);
    }
}
```

```
//Invokes low_level_lib::store_buffer_data in constructor with usage::dynamic
my_buffer frequently_changing_buffer{some_data}; 

//Invokes low_level_lib::store_buffer_data in constructor with usage::static
const my_buffer never_changing_buffer{some_other_data};
```

The given example doesn't compile (`a type qualifier cannot be used on a constructor or destructor`), but it is only meant to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. Is it possible to do something like this in C++ and if yes, then how?

Comment: No it's not possible. A common workaround is to use argument overloads, so you have a "tag" that is passed for the `usage::static` constructor.

Comment: This sounds like a job for tag/type dispatch.  Either make `my_buffer` a template and  make the constructor conditional based on the type, or overload the constructor for different creation tags so you can specify you want the "const" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a tag type:

```
class const_tag {};
```

And use it to overload your constructors:

```
my_buffer(const data* const data_to_store_)
{
    id = low_level_lib::create_buffer();
    low_level_lib::store_buffer_data(id, usage::dynamic);
}

my_buffer(const data* const data_to_store_, const_tag)
{
    id = low_level_lib::create_buffer();
    low_level_lib::store_buffer_data(id, usage::static);
}
```

Or simply pass your `usage` as a constructor parameter:

```
my_buffer(const data* const data_to_store_, /* relevant type */ my_usage)
{
    id = low_level_lib::create_buffer();
    low_level_lib::store_buffer_data(id, my_usage);
}
```

Comment: Notice through that it is just a workaround and can be misused.